# How to detect a memory overrun?

Tags: c++, memory

How to detect memory overrun in your 24/7 application, such as an online game server? The system and tool is linux + gcc.

Sometimes the cause of the memory overrun is writing the memory beyond the array; and sometimes the cause of the memory overrun is invalid pointers.

So, does anyone have some experience with this and know how to prevent it?

Comment: IMHO the best way to detect memory overrun is testing and debugging, but maybe my way of thinking is to mainstream.

Comment: @Hauleth: http://blog.thirstybear.co.uk/2007/07/i-wouldnt-start-from-here.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prevention (at code level):

- Watch out the warnings of your compiler
- Use a static code checker
- Use strong coding guidelines

Detection (at run-time):

- Use tools like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), [efence](http://linux.die.net/man/3/efence), ... to analyse the behaviour of your program

Comment: Here is a list of tools http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis. Actually I also use PC-Lint (or Flexe-Lint its unix variant) as it is small and easy to use and configure. splint and cpplint are not feature-wise so far. Problems with static code checkers is that you only see one "translation-unit" and not overall problems. For buffer overruns with fixed size arrays it is ok but if you use pointers the checker will have difficulties in knowing how big the buffer is. But worth a try...

Comment: Yes but not good enough :-) static code checkers make far more checks than a compiler will ever do. The goal of a compiler is to translate the source in machine code and that so fast as possible. The goal of a static code checker is to find issues in the source code. Compilers would not be very efficient/usable if they would perform also deep code analysis...

Comment: the Valgrind may effect the server's performance;I can only use it in the test environment but not the real environment.And somtimes the problem only appear in the real environment,such as online game;so the memory overrun problem bothering me for a long time.

Comment: Yes that sounds like a big headache, but I fear there is no better solution. Maybe by chance you will find the issue by analyzing the code, but dynamic tools only detect issues that actually occur and need a triggering test case. Finding a way to reproduce the problem is the key... But often hangs high enough to need a big effort reaching it. Good luck!

Comment: I agree with you,actually I'm a leader of development department for Online Game and I found Memory Overrun problem cost us much time sometime;so I want to find some way to reduce them;But now, I think the key is the developer and what I can do is emphasize it again and again. So thank you very much, jdehaan.

Answer (score 2):

You redefine your memory allocation function (e.g. `malloc`) to allocate a bigger buffer than is needed to store the allocation, and you fill the additional space with known pattern, and you regularly check that the pattern has not been corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

Run your program using [valgrind's memory check](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html).

Unit test you code as much as possible, and again execute then using [valgrind's memory check](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html).

Comment: the valgrind will effect the server's performance,so I can only use it in test environment;but some bug only happend

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, use `valgrind` during testing, and test exhaustively.  For protection at run-time, it's possible to replace the global `operator new` and `operator delete`: the replacements should maintain a guard block on both sides of the returned block: `operator new` initializes the guard blocks to a predefined pattern, and `operator delete` verifies that that pattern is still present.  `operator delete` should also overwrite the actual memory with a distinctive pattern (**not** all 0's), to increase the probability that using a dangling pointer will be detected.

Using `std::vector`, and particularly a debugging version of `std::vector`, for **all** arrays, should prevent all overwriting, and detect it immediately, at the site it occurs (as opposed to when you finally free the memory).  The performance hit might be too much to leave all of the checking in the final application, however (but it's worth a try).

Comment: And how to use a debugging version of vector?

Comment: I have know,compile the application with the -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG compile flag:)

Comment: @markmao It depends on the compiler: its on by default under Visual Studio (at least in debug builds); for g++, as you say, `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` (with perhaps `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC` as well).  Other compilers will require different options.

Comment: you are right,and another question:you said 'operator new' initializes the guard blocks to a predefined pattern,and how to set the blocks to predefined pattern?

Comment: @markmao You implement the `operator new`, so you do what you want.  Assuming an 8 byte guard, you allocate 16 bytes more than requested (using `malloc`), then copy the pattern into the first and last 8 bytes, and return a pointer to behind the initial pattern.  You actually need to allocate even a bit more, and save the requested size in the header as well.  In `operator delete`, you subtract the size of the header from given pointer, and verify that the guard values have not changed.

Comment: I had researched it today and I found the way as you said. otherwise, I found Electric Fence which is a memory debugger, it seems useful sometimes.