# vector push_back std::length_error: vector" failed

Tags: c++

I have a problem, I need to `push_back` a srtuct. structure is like that.

```
struct RChar
{
  int x;
  int y;
  string letter;
}
struct PResult
{
  int conf;
  string name;
  std::vector<RChar> char_details;
};
class IResults
{
  IResults(){};
  ~IResults(){};
  float processing_time_ms;
  int index;
  std::vector<PResult> topPResults;

};

// use case
 
IResults* myres = new IResults();
PResult res;
res.conf = 30;
res.name = "xyz";
......
......
myres->topPResults.push_back(res); // here a run time exception thrown
```

In above code i am performing a simple operation. the exception thrown on run time is `A/libc: /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-release-r20/external/libcxx/../../external/libcxxabi/src/abort_message.cpp:73: abort_message: assertion "terminating with uncaught exception of type std::length_error: vector" failed`.
The exception looks like vector memory allocation failed. I am unable to trace the issue exactly what is causing the problem here.

Comment: can you show more code?

Comment: could you show the constructor of IResults?

Comment: This is the kind of problem best solved with a debugger. My best guess is that the vector's memory is corrupted, possibly due to a use-after-free. Why are you using a raw pointer to the `IResults`?

Comment: We welcome examples that are just enough code to compile and reproduce the problem, a.k.a. [mcve]. That being said, and aside from the question, your code shows various bad practices (manual memory management, failure to RAII, direct access to member variables). You might want to seek advice on those.

Comment: `......` is not C++ code.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Same issue if i do not use raw pointer

Comment: @Villance [Start with this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/78f5d502d2f61798).  Now add and/or remove code until the error is duplicated.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It is a cross platform application it works fine 64 bit linux OS but failed on Android 10.

Comment: @Villance -- Until you come up with an [mcve], your application could be exhibiting undefined behavior, and the Android 10 is giving you hints that your application is buggy.  If you took the code I posted at that coliru link, compiled it and ran it on both platforms, do you get an exception thrown?

Comment: `new IResults()` shouldn't even compile if done outside the class itself since the default constructor is `private`.

Comment: @Villance: You should get rid of the idea that you are debugging an *application*. The problem is not the application, the problem is some code construct *within* the application that is causing trouble. (Likely in the "..." part.) The first part of debugging is to *find* that construct, isolate it into a stand-alone example (which need not have *any* functionality *other than triggering that error that is bothering you*). That is something StackOverflow cannot really help you with. Once you *have* isolated the issue, we *can* tell you what the actual problem is, and how to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a memory overrun somewhere. The `vector` container is a data structure with pointers; if some other code writes over these pointers, it tries to access invalid memory and fails.

The exception type (`length_error`) may or may not be relevant. Imagine some faulty code wrote `-1` over the length member of the `vector` class - this would confuse the `vector` code to think its length is invalid.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8309308/509868) for details on how to fix.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, all memory tests were successful and working on 64 bit linux OS but on Android OS the exception occurred.

Comment: If raw pointer is the issue I replaced `IResults* myres = new IResults();` with this `IResults myres` the behavior did not change.